# How to fetch data from read-only mysql database using python?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I am trying to fetch data in python from MySQL database using username that has read-only permission. I am using mysql.connector package to connect to database.

It gets connected to database properly, as I checked using following:

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host = HOSTNAME, user = USERNAME, passwd = PASSWORD, db = DATABASE, port=PORT)
print(connection.cmd_statistics())
```

But when I try to fetch data from Database using cursor, it returns 'None'.
My code is:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
try:
    query1 = 'SELECT * FROM table_name'
    result = cursor.execute(query1)
    print(result)
finally:
    connection.close()
```

And the output is:
*None*

Comment: Because you've caught and hidden every possible exception. *Don't do that*.

Comment: Still output is None

Comment: You forgot to obtain the result: `results = cursor.fetchall()`

Comment: @9dogs thank you very much. That is quite embarrassing though.

Answer (score 0):

## It works for python 3.6.5 and mysql_workbench 8.0 but not tried in other python -version**

```
import _mysql_connector    
avi = _mysql_connector.MySQL()
avi.connect(host='127.0.0.1',user='root',port=3306, password='root',database='hr_table')

avi.query("select * from hr_table.countries")
row = avi.fetch_row()
while row:
  print(row)
  row = avi.fetch_row()
avi.free_result()
avi.close()
```